# Integrate $\int_0^{\infty} e^{x-ex} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate $\int_0^{\infty} e^{x-ex} dx$.

I'm having a hard time integrating this...

I tried u-substitution. But at one point you get $\infty-\infty$.

According to online calculator, the answer seems to be $\frac{1}{e-1}$.

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Put $y=(e-1)x$.

Comment: The integrand function is $ \ e^{(1 \ - \ e )x} $ , which "decays" exponentially, so the improper integral will converge to a finite value.

Comment: Can't we write x(1-e) and directly solve to get -1/(1-e)?

Comment: The sequence of [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4017052) seems to converge ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{x-ex} dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(e-1)x} =-\frac{e^{-(e-1)x}}{e-1}|_{0}^{\infty}=\frac{1}{e-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=(1-e)x$, then we have
$$
\int_0^{\infty}e^{x-ex}\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{1-e}\int_0^{-\infty}e^{y}\mathrm{d}y = \frac{1}{e-1}.
$$